# Methods to work with offline primary keys

Tags: gnupg

I created a number of profiles with separate subkeys for authentication, signature, and encryption while primary keys are saved on USB Stick. It's working alright but I was wondering if there are some good methods to link to a primary key when it is needed to certify certain operations, such as signing another key, adding identities etc.

I followed [this blog](https://incenp.org/notes/2015/using-an-offline-gnupg-master-key.html), which I thought would be a solution. I imported private keys into a temp gpg directory `~/ram/gpgtmp/` and tried to sign ID2 with ID1 both in a default folder `~/.gnupg/puring.kbx`.

```
gpg --homdir ~/ram/gpgtmp --keyring ~/.gnupg/pubring.kbx -u ID1 --edit-key ID2
```

The ID2 is not signed in a default gnupg folder but in `~/ram/gpgtmp`. I tested it when invoking command `gpg --homedir ~/ram/gpgtmp -k`. Therefore it is not necessarily working.

Do you know how to bring an offline primary key?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to link an offline primary key. Still, inspired by a blog [Using an offline GnuPG master key](https://incenp.org/notes/2015/using-an-offline-gnupg-master-key.html), I realised that `--keyring` adds a file to a list of keyrings, whereas I needed to specify exactly one file. Therefore, the missing option was `--no-default-keyring`. I am not an expert but this is what worked for me:

1) Mount USB stick. The folder will something like `/run/media/username/CORSAIR` in Linux.

2) Create directory for a ram disk

```
mkdir ~/ram
```

3) Mount the ram disk:

```
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=64M tmpfs ~/ram
```

4) Create a temporary directory for gpg: `mkdir ~/ram/gpgtmp`.

5) Import private keys from a USB to a temp gpg , e.g.

```
gpg --homedir ~/ram/gpgtmp --import /run/media/username/CORSAIR/gpg-archive/primary-keys.asc
```

*After importing private keys to ram disk, USB stick is no longer needed.*

6) Run GPG editor:

```
gpg --homedir ~/ram/gpgtmp/ --keyring ~/.gnupg/pubring.kbx --no-default-keyring -u <ID1> --edit-key <ID2>
```

7) In the editor, use `uid n` to choose an identity of interest, followed by `sign` to sign selected identity with a local key .

With a primary key linked to a temp gpg folder, the command should be completed with success. As a side note, after step 5 a USB stick is no longer reuqired and can be dismounted.

---

EDIT.

In case of error:

```
gpg: key AAAAAAAAAAAAA: error sending to agent: No such file or directory
```

try to restart gpg-agent

```
gpgconf --kill gpg-agent
gpgconf --launch gpg-agent
```

I also deleted everything in gpgtmp. Even better would be to re-create the folder. After re-launching the gpg-agent, the import was working again. I guess a simple restart system would also work.